# Did Narcissa Malfoy save Harry's life?

Tags: harry-potter

Did Narcissa Malfoy save Harry's life?

Comment: In the sense that if she'd shouted "***He's still alive!!!***" Voldemort would have zapped him again, yes.

Comment: Probably answered here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10127/why-did-narcissa-malfoy-lie-about-harry?rq=1

Comment: Harry couldn’t die at this point since Voldemort was still alive, so probably not.

Answer (score 7):

Short Answer: **Yes.**

---

Longer answer: **Indubitably.**  Narcissa was sent to check on Harry to make sure he was dead, and this happened:

> “*Is Draco alive? Is he in the castle?*”
>
> The whisper was barely audible; her lips were an inch from his ear, her head bent so low that her long hair shielded his face from the onlookers.
>
> “Yes,” he breathed back.
>
> He felt the hand on his chest contract; her nails pierced him. Then it was withdrawn. She had sat up.
>
> “He is dead!” Narcissa Malfoy called to the watchers.

So yes, had she said that he was alive, Voldemort would have killed him again, or if that failed because of Lily's charm and/or Voldemort taking Harry's blood, a Death Eater would have killed him.

Of course, it is possible that a shout of "He's alive!" would send the good guys into a frenzy and they would somehow protect Harry.  But to answer your question: yes, Harry was in danger of dying, and yes, Narcissa Malfoy's actions eliminated that danger.  That's the definition of saving one's life.